# Differentiability of a complex valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Consider : $$f(z)=Arg(z)$$ where $Arg(z)$ is the the principal argument of $z\in \Bbb C$

Show that $f$ is nowhere differentiable in $\Bbb C$

I tried the solve this buy the definition of Differentiation but I could not get through.

Where should I begin?

Comment: Is it supposed to be known that it is nowhere differentiable?

Comment: Show that it is not continuous from $1-xi\to1+xi$, since $\arg(z)$ will go from $2\pi$ to $0$.

Comment: Try this:  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cauchy-RiemannEquations.html

Comment: @SimpleArt Yes it a well known that the Principal Argument is nowhere differentiable in the complex plane. I was just curious of knowing how could we prove it. I am sorry to say but I cant understand as to how your above comments will be useful to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was differentiable in some $z_0=r_0e^{it_0}$, use that $\displaystyle\lim_{r\to r_0}\frac{Arg(re^{it_0})-Arg(r_0e^{it_0})}{re^{it_0}-r_0e^{it_0}} = \lim_{t\to t_0}\frac{Arg(r_0e^{it})-Arg(r_0e^{it_0})}{r_0e^{it}-r_0e^{it_0}}$

Edit: As requested, here a further evaluation of RHS.

$\displaystyle\lim_{t\to t_0}\frac{Arg(r_0e^{it})-Arg(r_0e^{it_0})}{r_0e^{it}-r_0e^{it_0}} = \frac{1}{r_0}\lim_{t\to t_0}\frac{t-t_0}{e^{it}-e^{it_0}} \overset{(*)}{=} \frac{1}{r_0}\frac{1}{\lim_{t\to t_0}\frac{e^{it}-e^{it_0}}{t-t_0}} = \frac{1}{r_0}\frac{1}{ie^{it_0}}$

The (*) is justified a posteriori by the existence of the limit.

Comment: I guess that the LHS of the above equation is 0. But I am not sure as to how I can evaluate the RHS of the above equation.

Comment: If you exclude $t_0=0$ (where Arg is not even continuous, hence surely not differentiable), then we can assume that for a small enough neighborhood of $t_0$ we have $Arg(r_0 e^{it}) = t$. Similarly for the other summand. I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Wait! How can you assume that $Arg(r_0 e^{it})=t$ ? Here By $Arg(z)$ i mean the "principal argument" of $z$. Whereas the above angle $t$ is just an argument of the complex number. I hope you are getting my point.

Comment: You can assume $t_0$ to be the principal argument of $r_0e^{it_0}$ because there is of course a representation of $z_0$ with its principal argument. If you then exclude $t_0=0$ you get $t=Arg(e^{it})$ if $t$ is in a small neighborhood of $t_0$ because $(0,2\pi)$ is open.

Comment: So on the RHS  i should be getting indeterminate form. is that correct?

Comment: No you shouldn't, it is relatively easy to evaluate. If you can't do it, look at its inverse fraction.

Comment: I have always solved problems where we let $r \to r_o$ , this is the 1st time I am coming across a problem in which we let the angle $t \to t_0$. Can you please take the trouble of evaluating the RHS for me?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was really struggling with this problem. I sincerely appreciate you efforts.